# Choice Table-Column from a variable

Tags: sql, database

I have a table -> `table1`, which have 10 columns..
`Id`, `Day1`, `Day2`, `Day3`, `Day4`, `Day5`, ...

Now i create a new Day and want to reference the new Day to one of te column in my table1

Something like that:

```
    @Id AS int
    @Day AS nvarchar,
    @RefDayId AS int
AS
    UPDATE dbo.table1
    SET table1.@Day = @RefDayId
    WHERE table1.Id = @Id
    RETURN
```

I set @Day as "Day1" or as "Day2". But i know that this just do not work. I got the tip that it should work with the EXEC-Function, but i dont see a way there.
Something like this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-en/library/bb510489.aspx is what i'm searching for. 
But i don't use Transact-SQL, i'm using MSSQL Express 2010 Stored Procedure

Comment: Is there a need for table to be structured this way? Doesn't seem very usable to me.

Comment: We need that for a month-plan, we should do that with a seperate table, but we wanted it like this.

Comment: Well, you get what you asked for. :) Not all structures are created equal. Some are easier to work with than others.

Comment: We just don't want to make 10000 tables, and there will be not much data. their should be a way to do this..  with CASE WHEN.. or something like this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to use dynamic sql like this perhaps...

```
@Id AS int
@Day AS nvarchar,
@RefDayId AS int
AS
DECLARE @sql   varchar(500)
SELECT @sql = 'UPDATE dbo.table1 SET table1.'||@Day||' = '||@RefDayId||' WHERE table1.Id = '||@Id
EXECUTE(@sql)
RETURN
```

Comment: Thank you, but i got allready the answer, by my self: `EXEC('UPDATE dbo.table1 SET table1.Day' + Day + ' = ' + RefDayId + ' WHERE table1.Id = ' + Id)` Its just similar to yours.